# Jquery template button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have this script that makes a button... I need to make another script that tracks whenthe button is clicked.. how would i create that.

```
 <script id="navTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
{{if TotalItemCount==0}}<br/>No Matches.  Make sure your Marketing Info is complete.
{{else}}
<a href="#" class="rowSelectionPage" data-select="{{if AnyPageHasSelections}}false{{else}}true{{/if}}" data-selectmode="All" data-selectpageurl="PowerMatchingRowSelectionPage" >{{if AnyPageHasSelections}}un{{/if}}select entire list</a> / <a href="#" class="modalEdit" data-mode="send" data-bulkselectionmode="ServerSideRowSelections" data-method="GET" data-successmessage="Message Submitted" data-modalWidth="665" data-viewurl="/Marketing/Email/SendBuyerMatchesEmail?mode=ServerSideRowSelections&sellerId=${CaseId}" data-title="Send Email" title="Send New Email">email selected buyers</a><br />
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I don't see a `<button>` tag or `<input type="button">` element anywhere. Can you provide more info?

Comment: well its an anchor tag. So when that anchor tag is clicked i need to track when that happens.

Comment: Do some research about JavaScript events.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using some framework for binding. Without knowing exactly which one, I  can only offer that there may be a built-in binding for events. For example, in AngularJS there is a "ng-click" directive that facilitates binding a function to a standard JavaScript event.

In the absence of such a framework, then I agree with Zeaklous. You should be able to add an "onClick" event directly to your anchor tag.

```
<a href="#" onClick="my_tracking_function()" class="rowSelectionPage" data-select="{{if AnyPageHasSelections}}false{{else}}true{{/if}}" data-selectmode="All" data-selectpageurl="PowerMatchingRowSelectionPage" >{{if AnyPageHasSelections}}un{{/if}}select entire list</a>

<script>
      function my_tracking_function() {
           // Trigger some tracking event (i.e. ajax, count...)
      }
</script>
```